# Pymongo escaping unicode characters in field names

Tags: python, mongodb, unicode, pymongo

I have the following example key-value pair stored in MongoDB (and a number of similar pairs):

```
"Cl\uff0eG_bibcode": 'some value'
```

The reason it is stored like this is because MongoDB doesn't accept dots in the key name. Using the \uff0e unicode version of a dot has worked no problem thus far, but I have started using pymongo to pull in data from my db and it seems to be escaping the \uff0e. So when I look at it in my code it comes in like this:

```
"Cl\\uff0eG_bibcode": 'some value'
```

I've noticed it doesn't do this if the \uff0e is in the value, only if it's in the key. I'm also not manipulating the data at any point between Mongo and my code. This is all I'm doing:

```
url = 'mongodb://user:passwd@host/database'
client = MongoClient(url)
db = client.get_default_database()
collection = db['my_collection']
results = collection.find().limit(1) #just grabbing any record to test
```

I'm looking for some insight into how to get pymongo to stop escaping unicode characters in the key name. I'd really like to not have to go through all my results and get rid of it manually.

Comment: what happens in the mongo shell. add an example from the shell output.

Comment: the first example is what it looks like in the shell. `"Cl\uff0eG_bibcode": 'some value'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous driver you used may be escaping during insert. When done in my mongo shell, the following shows no encoding.

```
db.Junk.insert({"Cl\uff0eG_bibcode": "some value"})
db.Junk.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5487e53c64316c4cb2442578"), "Cl．G_bibcode" : "some value" }
```

Escaping it as such does show your result from the shell.

```
db.Junk.insert({"Cl\\uff0eG_bibcode": "some value"})
db.Junk.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5487e5fc64316c4cb2442579"), "Cl\uff0eG_bibcode" : "some value" }
```

Have you inserted the data directly via the shell?

Btw dots are accepted in the key name but they're interpreted as [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/) and therefore considered a subdocument. ie. a key of "user._id" will be interpreted as `the _id key inside the object (value) associated with the user key`

```
{ _id: value
  key1: "str_value",
  key2: 12345,
  user: { _id: xxx, name: xxxx}
}
```

Two suggestions. 
a) Why not use a pipe | ,  or some other simple but implausible (not likely to be used in any normal key) token. b) I would suggest hacking the BSON files and build in a encoder/decoder for your funky key. Possibly in this file. [https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/bson/**init**.py](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/bson/__init__.py)

Comment: I think you're right that this is happening on insert. We are scraping data from a poorly set up scientific database, hence the funky keys. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using python 2.x here, use unicode keys:

```
>>> c.foo.bar.insert({u'Cl\uff0eG_bibcode': 'some value'})
ObjectId('5488fe8dfba52249d72069bf')
>>> doc = c.foo.bar.find_one()
>>> doc
{u'_id': ObjectId('5488fe8dfba52249d72069bf'), u'Cl\uff0eG_bibcode': u'some value'}   
>>> for key in doc:
...     print key.encode("utf-8")
... 
_id
Cl．G_bibcode
```